# iOS - Retrieve and display an image from Parse in UIImageView (Swift 1.2 Error)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

I have previously been retrieving an image form my Parse backend to display in my app inside a UIImageView using the following lines of code:

```
let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()["picture"] as PFFile

userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData:NSData, error:NSError) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {

            self.dpImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData)

    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> 'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'PFFile'; did you mean to use 'as!'
>   to force downcast?

The 'helpful' Apple fix-it tip suggests the "as!" change so I add in the !, but then I get the error:

> 'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'PFFile'

With the 'getDataInBackgroundWithBlock' section, I also get the error:

> Cannot invoke 'getDataInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((NSData, NSError) -> Void)'

Can someone please explain how to correctly retrieve a photo from Parse and display it in a UIImageView using **Swift 1.2**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PFUser.currentUser()` returns optional type (`Self?`). So you should unwrap return value to access element by subscript.

```
PFUser.currentUser()?["picture"]
```

And the value got by subscript is also optional type. So you should use optional binding to cast the value because type casting may fail.

```
if let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()?["picture"] as? PFFile {
```

And parameters of the result block of `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock()` method are both optional type (`NSData?` and `NSError?`). So you should specify optional type for the parameters, instead `NSData` and `NSError`.

```
userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

The code modified the all above problems is below:

```
if let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()?["picture"] as? PFFile {
    userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.dpImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! If I had enough reputations I would upvote this! Only error Xcode gave me with this was to suggest I use a '!' mark after imageData like so: self.dpImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!). Once I did that change, it worked perfectly.

Comment: I can't make it work in swift2.1, it's returning nil.