# How to pass data from query - Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I have a query when `ViewDidLoad` and i want to pass it to `function tableview` so i can use it to write text into a label like `cell.textCell.text`

How can i do that? My code is showing me blank rows.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ListaTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var queryArray: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurantes")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Restaurantes.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    if let pfObject: PFObject = objects as? PFObject {

                        self.queryArray.append(pfObject as PFObject)

                    }


                    //     println(object.objectId)

                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return queryArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ListaTableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListaTableViewCell
    println("hey")

    cell.textCell.text = queryArray[indexPath.row]["nome"] as? String

    cell.imageBg.image = UIImage(named: "www.maisturismo.jpg")


    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `self.tableView.reloadData()`

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ListaTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var queryArray: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurantes")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Restaurantes.")
            if let _objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                self.queryArray = _objects
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return queryArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ListaTableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListaTableViewCell
    let restaurante = queryArray[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
    cell.textCell.text = restaurante.objectForKey("nome") as! NSString
    cell.imageBg.image = UIImage(named: "www.maisturismo.jpg")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Same. White rows... I dont know what to do... Im trying to fix this for hours. The problem is here:    `cell.textCell.text = queryArray[indexPath.row]["nome"] as? String`

Comment: Maybe your problem is `ListaTableViewCell` or `queryArray[indexPath.row]["nome"] as? String` is nil.. You need to check `queryArray.count` has the correct size.. If yes, your problem is with your cell.

Comment: Dont return anything. =/

Comment: wthat it prints? `println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Restaurantes.")`. `objects!.count` is more than 0?

Comment: I edited `[PFObject] to `PFOject` and returns 8 (its right)

Comment: Sorry, changes to `self.queryArray = _objects`

Comment: Is everything ok now?

Comment: HELL YEA!!! 
One last question: And for images? Its not working this way:
`cell.imageBg.image = restaurante.objectForKey("imagem1") as! UIImage`

Comment: For images you have other workaround. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29730286/846780