# Retrive an image into UiimageView from Parse (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

I've been trying to load an image from Parse.com into a uiimageview inside of my storyboard.

I uploaded an image to Parse. Ideally, it would call my image by an ID and then proceed to display it inside of a uiimageView . I've searched high and low for an answer, but most are either for Obj-C or only include half the code to call an image.

I'm aiming for an image to be displayed which I can update daily.

Here is my code so far. It runs without errors but no image appears.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

            //Print out a message if we're able to get to this part of the program.
    print("Reached getProductData function. Now asking for data.")
    getProductData()
    print("done");



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getProductData () //-> UIImage
{
    let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserPhoto")
    var gridimage = UIImage()
    print("pass");
    //call function to get the data from parse by specifyng an objectId
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("XXXXXXXXXX") {
        (productData:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && productData != nil {
            //Extract values from the productData PFObject and store them in constants
            //-----start image loading
            print("ok")
            if let productImageFile = productData!["productImage"] as? PFFile {
                productImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        //here I changed var gridimage to just gridimage
                        gridimage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        self.eliegrid.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                        print("next")


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("error")
                    }
                }
            }

            //-----end image loading

        } else if error != nil {
            print("Could not load data from Parse")

        }


    }
    //return gridimage
}
```

}

It seems like it skips this block:

```
if let productImageFile = productData!["productImage"] as? PFFile {
```

EDIT: Because it never prints "next".

I've also checked out

> [iOS - Retrieve and display an image from Parse in UIImageView (Swift 1.2 Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729883/ios-retrieve-and-display-an-image-from-parse-in-uiimageview-swift-1-2-error?rq=1)

But it still doesn't work.

I'm really new to both Parse and Swift, and I may be missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @beyowulf! Here is the working code:

```
 func getProductData () 
{
    let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserPhoto")
    var gridimage = UIImage()
    print("pass");
    //call function to get the data from parse by specifyng an objectId
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("cF0h6RVcKu") {
        (productData:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && productData != nil {
            //Extract values from the productData PFObject and store them in constants
            //-----start image loading
            print("ok")
            print(productData)
            if let productImageFile = productData!["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                productImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("error")
                    if error == nil {
                        //here I changed var gridimage to just gridimage
                        gridimage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                        self.eliegrid.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                        print("next")



                    }
                }
            }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("error")
                    }
                }
            }
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you have an image on Parse? Can you check on parse.com ?

Comment: Yes, I have an image on Parse.com. I've checked and double-checked on my backend online.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move :

```
func getProductData () -> UIImage
    {
        var gridimage = UIImage()
        print("pass");
        //call function to get the data from parse by specifyng an objectId
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("XXXXXXXXXX") {
            (productData:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && productData != nil {
                //Extract values from the productData PFObject and store them in constants
                //-----start image loading
                print("ok")
                //var imageFromParse = object?.objectForKey("imageNews") as? PFFile
                //imageFromParse!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    //var image: UIImage! = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                    //cell?.imageViewCell?.image = image
                //})
                if let productImageFile = productData!["productImage"] as? PFFile {
                productImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            var gridimage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                            self.eliegrid.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                            print("next")


                        }
                    }
                }



            } else if error != nil {
                print("Could not load data from Parse")

            }


        }
     return gridimage
    }
```

out of viewDidLoad then delete:

```
print("done");
    self.eliegrid.image = getProductData()
```

From the bottom of viewDidLoad. You are calling a function that goes out of scope before the completion block can be executed that is why it's not firing. It is not a very swift-y thing to nest functions in this manner and is almost never advisable.

Also try changing:

```
if let productImageFile = productData!["productImage"] as? PFFile {
                productImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            var gridimage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                            self.eliegrid.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                            print("next")


                        }
                    }
                }
```

To:

```
                let productImageFile = productData.valueForKey("productImage") as! PFFile 
                productImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            var gridimage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                            self.eliegrid.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                            print("next")


                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Where would I move all the code to?

Comment: Below the "}" for the end of viewDidLoad. It just needs to be it's own function not nested in another.

Comment: Ok. I tried what you guys offered but it still doesn't appear inside the uiimageview. Check my original question for the edited code!

Comment: What does it print? Does it print "pass"? "ok"? "next"?

Comment: It prints: "Reached getProductData function. Now asking for data.
pass 
done 
ok"   Any ideas?

Comment: But not "next"? So it's not getting the image. Before the if error == nil try placing print(error)

Comment: No, not "next". I put "print("error") before "if error == nil" and the "error" did not get printed. Thanks for the continuing help.

Comment: @beyowulf you should let the `as?` instead of `as!` or get rid of `if let`

Comment: It now tells me "Value of type PFObject not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or ?". If I add a "!" it says:  "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not PFFile"   Any suggestions?

Comment: Basically just get it so there's no "if let" statement if it's going to crash it's better we see that. You can also put print(productData) above the if let so we can see if there's a "productImage" key.

Comment: Ok. The "print(productData)" gave me:  Optional(<UserPhoto: 0x7f939b771b60, objectId: cF0h6RVcKu, localId: (null)> {
    imageFile = "<PFFile: 0x7f939b781be0>";
    imageName = test;
})    |  It seems to me like this is the correct info.

Comment: So the key is "imageFile" not "productImage"

Comment: Yes! This was the problem. I changed the key as you said and it showed the image I had previously uploaded. Thank you. I've updated my original question with the code that worked.